# iOS - Status bar does not appear on iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, statusbar, launchimage

My app is not showing status bar in iPhone 6/6+.  If I supply the launch images for iPhone 6/6+, status bar shows.  Any idea what's causing the status bar to not appear? Is there any way to make it appear without having to run the app in native resolution?

Comment: have you set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` and `UIStatusBarHidden` values (depending on the targeted iOS version) in your `info.plist`?

Comment: Yes - UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance is set to NO.  I noticed if I background the app and foreground it, the status bar shows up.  Looks like an SDK bug to me.